# windows 8 phone application

Tags: windows-phone-8, development-environment

I am new to windows phone app development. I want to build apps for Windows Phone 7/7.5/8

I have a set of doubts about the environment setup:

1. Should we need windows8 0S for developing  apps ?
2. Can we develop apps in windows vista OS.
3. Can you please name what tools required for windows app development? What all in need to download? where can I find?

A beginners guide to develop application would be much appreciated.

Comment: have you searched on the Internet for answers at all? One google search for each question, and you will solve the problem yourself!

Comment: @Axarydax Three months ago I spent literally days trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, you need Windows 8. The IDE will not install on an older OS.

   Moreover, you need Windows 8 64-bit if you want to be able to run the Windows Phone emulator on which you can see/debug your programs.

   Moreover, your computer needs to be modern enough, the processor must support Hyper-V virtualization which is another prerequisite for the Windows Phone emulator. If you don't have this support, then again, you won't be able to debug on the emulator. You can use [coreinfo](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc835722.aspx) to learn whether your computer qualifies.
2. No. The only thing you can do on Windows Vista is run a virtual machine with Windows 8. Make sure your virtualization software supports Hyper-V, and the guest Windows 8 OS is 64-bit.
3. You need [Windows Phone SDK](http://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/downloadsdk). That is all.

Also note that in order to debug your application on an actual phone you will need a [developer account at Microsoft](http://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/join). This costs $99 per year. If you're a student (and can prove that to Microsoft in some way), you will be granted with a free-of-charge account.

The account lets you to unblock up to three actual phone devices for development. You'll be able to install your program only on those. In order to install on other phones, you will need to upload your program to Windows Store.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, you need windows 8 for WP8 development.
2. No, you need Windows 8 for WP8 development (although you can use XP or greater for WP7.5)
3. Windows Phone SDK 8.0